# Ошибка php artisan optimize mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

Tags: laravel, composer, outofmemoryerror, artisan

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто-нибудь , знаете в чем проблема? После того как клонирую репозиторий, vendor удаляю и делаю заново composer install , после чего автоматически выполняется artisan optimize и дальше идет эта ошибка? Что может ее спровоцировать и как быть? раньше ничего подобного не было

Comment: Удалите кэш композера. sudo rm -R ~/.composer
Удалите вендоры. Запустите composer update

Comment: Не помогает (на текст в скобках не обращать внимания, это для мин. комментария требует стэковерфлов)

Comment: Решили проблему??